# How to make a webpage look same on different screens?

Tags: css, screen, fullscreen

I have a [webpage](http://ferhan.ferohost.com) made by me. There are few contents in it which are looking different on different screens (eg: mac and windows).

When I am trying to open the same webpage on my DELL laptop(Windows 10), there are few things which are looking different on another screen size computers.

On different screen size computer; the boxes section, the "See More" text, and the "Sales" text currently looks like this(which is not I want):

"See More" text

[image]

"Sales" text

[image]

Boxes section:

[image]

And the same link, when I am trying to open on my desktop which has bigger screen, it is looking in this way(which is I want):

Boxes section:

[image]

"See More" text:

[image]

"Sales" text:

[image]

I am wondering, what changes do I need to make in my CSS so that it looks same on different screens.

The CSS code which I am using for the boxes are:

```
.company-heads {
    margin-left: 300px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-right: 289px
}

.company-heads .rectangle {
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 22px;
    width: 355px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.company-heads .rectangle .circle {
    background: #aaa;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Are the screen sizes the same width on both laptops? You should use a percentage width for the rectangles so they scale when the page gets narrower.

Comment: @JoelB No screen sizes are different on both devices. Can you let me know on where I have to change my code in CSS ?

Comment: @JoelB I am using  `width: 45%;` I have replaced this with pixels.

Comment: @JoelB Do you want me to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by giving the parent container, `.company-heads`, in this case, a max-width! Looks like, `.company-heads { max-width: 1140px; }` will do the job. Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem!

Comment: Using this is making the boxes aligned towards the left of the screen.

Comment: Instead of explicitly specifying `margin-left` and `margin-right`, try giving `.company-heads { margin: 0 auto; }` as well, to automatically center it.